# I am trying to extract text content from HTML using Jsoup. "b<h1>etwe</h1>en" gets converted to "b etween"

Tags: jsoup

"English" gets converted to "Engl ish"
How to avoid getting this unnecessary space in the extracted text?

Comment: Use String methods to solve like these problems

Comment: @Hexaholic  `package TestPackage;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class SampleJsoup {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  String fragment = "<p>Th<b>is Nond</b>isclosure A<i>greem</i>ent (Agreem<u>ent) is b</u>y and b<h1>etwe</h1>en Insert name of the other party , an  <b>Insert applicable incorporation laws </b>Engl<h2>ish cor</h2>poration <h3>with </h3>its prin<strike>cipal </strike>place of business at ('Company') and";
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(fragment);
  String text = doc.body().text();
  System.out.println(text);
 }
}`

Comment: @JavaFan Please check the code above. Which String methods are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to extract each  node alone   and use  String.concat()  method  to join the separated Strings . e.g

```
fragment.select("b").text().concat(fragment.select("i").text());
```